# get_term_by seems to be failing

Tags: taxonomy

Code:

```
print_r($wp->query_vars);
echo "<br><br>".get_query_var('term');
echo "<br><br>".get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
echo "<br><br>$term";
```

Output:

```
Array ( [titles] => windows-powershell-v2 [taxonomy] => titles [term] => windows-powershell-v2 ) 

windows-powershell-v2

titles
```

As you can see, the first three lines run fine. The fourth line fails with no error - but it terminates page execution. The specified term does indeed exist in the taxonomy; this is being reached with the URL /titles/windows-powershell-v2/.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) returns object by default. Which should end up in `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` if you try to echo it. Likely you have errors suppressed.

Try `var_dump( $term );` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Yup. Finally figured that out just as you posted. Duh. That could be better-documented, but I wanted $term->name.

Comment: Most functions that deal with terms return objects, there are simply way more to term than name alone. Run test environment with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` makes life much easier when you see errors.